# ¿Como cerrar un form completo y no solo lo de dentro de un panel?

Tags: vb.net, formularios

Buenas estoy realizando un pequeño sistema de tarea, y me encontré con un problema, estoy usando varios forms pero tengo un header que siempre es el mismo y tiene las mismas opciones, por lo que opte a crear un form exclusivo para este header y así mandarlo a llamar desde cualquier otro form, este header tiene opciones para abrir otro form y que se cierre en el que se estaba actualmente, entonces como yo meto el header dentro de un panel en cualquier form, al abrir otro form, simplemente el panel es el que se cierra pero el form completo no se cierra, alguna idea de como cerrarlo?

La parte gris es el panel y dentro de este esta el form llamado header que lo uso para cualquier otro form
[image]

Y cuando doy click para abrir otro form y que se cierre el anterior solamente se cierra lo que esta dentro del panel y obvio porque en el metodo lo tengo como que se cierre solamente ese header, pero como le haría para que se cerrara todo el anterior?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: EL header deberia ser un user control. Si no, como estas metiendo un form dentro de otro? o solo los estas pegando?

Comment: Usa el boton [edit]. agrega todo en la pregunta ;)

Comment: Andre, edita tu pregunta con toda la informacion necesaria!

Comment: Lee por favor [ask] y tambien hace el [tour]